# Using regular expression in SQL select statement to find 11 digit numbers

Tags: sql, sql-server, regex

I am trying to match a regular expression using SQL where I can return the details of only accounts whose AccountNumber is an 11 digit. I have used the following but it does not seem to be working:

```
 select New_New_AccountNumber, New_PremiseNo, New_FirstName, New_LastName         
 from AccountExtensionBase
 where New_AccountNumber like '^\d{11}$'
 and New_AccountStage = 7
 order by New_FirstName
```

Comment: What database platform? Why the leading whitespace? Do you need ^$ anchors?

Comment: I had those in too doesnt seem to be helping changed the above

Comment: Can you post some sample or create a SQL Fiddle?

Comment: Sorry I am using SQL server I thought I had included this in the question title apologies

Comment: Which DBMS you are using? And what is the datatype for New_AccountNumber column?

Comment: @Jay - I didn't answer your question neither did I mark down your question.

Comment: Have you installed any kind of RegEx parser in SQL server then?

Answer (score 4):

SQL Server 2008 does not support Regular Expressions with `LIKE` or anything else, it uses simple pattern matching wildcards only.

Simple option;

```
select * from t where f like '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
```

Answer (score 3):

Regex won't work, but that could simply be replaced with [ISNUMERIC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186272.aspx) and [LEN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190329.aspx) as in:

```
where LEN(AccountNumber) = 11 and ISNUMERIC(AccountNumber)
```

Comment: An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'and'.

Comment: `select ISNUMERIC('.')`

Comment: `ISNUMERIC()` checks for values other than digits.

Answer (score 2):

This is similar to `isnumeric()`, but it only allows digits:

```
where len(New_AccountNumber) = 11 and
      New_AccountNumber not like [^0-9]
```

That is, the length is 11 and it contains not characters that are not digits.

Comment: @Rohit . . . I would much rather that SQL Server supported real regular expressions, but it does the job.

Answer (score 0):

I think this could be helpful

```
select New_New_AccountNumber, New_PremiseNo, New_FirstName, New_LastName
from AccountExtensionBase
where New_AccountNumber REGEXP '^[0-9]{11}$'
and New_AccountStage = 7
order by New_FirstName
```

the example above working with MySQL and can be used if someone need it.

This should work for SQL Server, I've tested with 2012 version, for different versions(2005,2008,...) it could need some corrections.

```
select New_New_AccountNumber, New_PremiseNo, New_FirstName, New_LastName
from AccountExtensionBase
where New_AccountNumber not like '%.%' and ISNUMERIC(New_AccountNumber)=1 and LEN(New_AccountNumber)=11
and New_AccountStage = 7
order by New_FirstName
```

Comment: SQL Server does not support regular expressions; nor is `REGEXP` valid syntax.

Comment: I have seen several answers to other questions like this but as Gordon mentioned the REGEXP does not seem to be valid syntax for MS SQL Server 2008

Comment: Yes, that's right. But my second query does not contain any REGEXP.